# Auto Complete Popup not working properly on cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to explain it properly,so i have added the image,please help me with this and please dont down vote.

Hi i am cloning the div on button click,and i want the auto complete box on the cloned elements also. on first element it is working fine but on cloned element the auto complete box(popup) is showing on 1st element but it should be shown on newly created textbox

following is the html code

```
<div class="repeatingSection">
<input id="Jobs[0].SampleType" name="Jobs[0].SampleType" type="text" class="form-control classSampleType" placeholder="Sample Name" required />
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning buttonGray buttonRight addJob">Add Job</a>
```

following is the js code for cloning

```
function resetAttributeNames(section) {
    var tags = section.find('input,button'), idx = section.index();
    tags.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.each(attrs, function (i, attr) {
            var attr_val = $this.attr(attr);
            if (attr_val) {
                $this.attr(attr, attr_val.replace(/\[\d\]/,'['+(idx-5)+']'))
            }
        })
    })
}

$('.addJob').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
    var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true)

    cloned.find("input").val("");

    cloned.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
    resetAttributeNames(cloned)
});
```

and following is the code for auto completion

```
$(".classSampleType").click(function () {
        var index = $(".classSampleType").index(this);

        $("#Jobs\\["+index+"\\]\\.SampleType").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Lab/GetSampleType",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    });
```

For Reference i have added the image [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb6w2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked for me by making following changes

```
var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true,false)
```

---

```
$(document).on('click','.classSampleType',function () {
    var index = $(".classSampleType").index(this);

    $("#Jobs\\["+index+"\\]\\.SampleType").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Lab/GetSampleType",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { Prefix: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
});
```